# Is there a way to tilt all points on a curve torwards the center of the world?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm modelling a street around a planet with an increasingly complex Terrain. I used the Shrinkwrap modifier in the beginning which worked well as long as my planet was just a sphere.

By adding more points to the curve and adjusting hights and positions my curve starts to twist in strange ways.

Since I don't see a way to "lock" the tilt of the other points I'm re-tilting points over and over wich starts to drive me crazy.

Is there a way to select all points and tell their Up-Vector to look torwards the center of the worldspace? I know there is the "Track To Constraint" Feature wich does the trick for Objects. But its not working in the *Edit Mode*.

If anybody could point me in the right direction I'd be extremely thankfull!!

[image: Twisting Points]

Comment: As far as I know there is no native way or tools to do it. Might be relatively easy to achieve with some sort of custom script

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with scripts in Blender yet I will have to look into that. Thanks for the advice.